# How do I mod_rewrite this URL?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL

`www.domain.com/catalog.php?category_title=widgets`

I want to mod_rewrite it to

`www.domain.com/widgets/`

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /([^/.]+)/[?]*[^\/\.]*$ /catalog.php?category_title=$1
```

So I'm searching for `/([^/.]+)/`

The `[?]*[^\/\.]*` part is so that the page can work with Google Adwords which appends a query string to the flat URL.

This regex worked on a a previous implementation using Zeus's Request Rewrite Module which is their proprietary version of mod_rewrite.

This is my first go at Apache mod_rewrite, and I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /catalog.php?category_title=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Almost, I need the trailing slash at the end. ^([^/]*)/$

Comment: Ah yeah missed that one out sorry!!